# Copied link in Mac OS has bogus Pasted-Contact.vcf

Tags: macos, qt

In Mac, when I am  creating a link from my client application and pasting it into the Apple client mail, the link pasted is junky .vcf contact instead of a text link. My client application is showing the link url in a QT window.

However, if I paste the copied link into an application such as TextEdit, I get the expected URL. One solution is to  copy/paste that URL from TextEdit into Mac Mail and then get the expected behaviour of a clickable link.

Any idea why am I getting such bogus contact .vcf ?

Comment: Another Observation : In some Mac machines, when I right click on Apple mail client and paste, it works correctly. But, after copying it to clipboard, when I tried command + V in the Apple mail client, it did not copy anything (not even .vcf file). Any idea guys ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in Mac for clipboard.setText() API where where the UTI is 
not getting set correctly. Hence, following a different approach for Mac. On viewing with Clipboardviewer in Mac, it was observed that the link url is stored in 10 different clipboard-spaces. One of them(the problematic one) is called public.vcard. So whenever content of clipboard is pasted into another application, it is up to the application to decide which clipboard space to use. Apple Mail apperently chooses "public.vcard" or "Apple VCard pasteboard type". 
This is a bug reported for Mac in QT (https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-48953)

Reference links : https://github.com/owncloud/client/issues/3300

I have fixed this for Mac using the following code :

```
import os 
data = "hello world"
os.system("echo '%s' | pbcopy" % data)
```